# App crashes when there is no image Swift 4

Tags: swift, uiimageview, image-caching

My app which I have made in `swift 4` crashes when a news provider does not have an image! So when I scroll over an article which does not have an image it crashes and I get the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code for the image:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImage(from url: String){
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    image = nil
    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: url as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        self.image = imageFromCache
        return
    }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }    
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: url as AnyObject)
            self.image = imageToCache
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is crashing? And why do you have so many crash operators (`!`) in your code?

Comment: @rmaddy imageCaching.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: url as AnyObject) **That is the line that is crashing**

Comment: It seems like you've provided the answer as part of the question.  If you don't have an image, don't try to use it as if you did.

Comment: @PhillipMills So if it doesn’t find an image from the Json file it crashes basically

Comment: Only if you use something like `imageToCache!` to guarantee that the value won't be nil.  You broke your promise; it crashed.  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills I would like some help. I’m really new to swift

Comment: I think your best source of help would be to read about Swift Optionals.  Whenever you use `!`, you're saying that even though it's an optional value you **KNOW** it's not nil.  In other words, don't do that unless you must.  Use `if let` to test whether you have something valid or not.